# How to create a grey-ish transparent text box with CSS/HTML?

Tags: html, css

I recently came across this beautiful website of a restaurant (Here's the link: https://sweetbasilvail.com/) And I wanted to know how to code its menu. Specifically I want to know how to make that grey-ish transparent box, and also the mouse over function that makes the sub-menus appear. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do what we'd do. Look at the source code.

Comment: It doesn't show the CSS part. Only the HTML. Unless I missed something .__. Currently on my program I see my "menu", but it doesn't have the mouse over and show sub menu functionality, no grey box either

Comment: You need to inspect the page using developer tools

Comment: If you just look at the source code you see that he uses a transparent image as background: https://sweetbasilvail.com/wp-content/themes/sweetbasil/images/bg_transp.png

Answer (score 0):

The menu boxes simply have a transparent image as background, set this way:

```
background: url("images/bg_transp.png") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

The image used is https://sweetbasilvail.com/wp-content/themes/sweetbasil/images/bg_transp.png